# Allow Drafting Emails which are sent from chatter component on Opportunity object

Tags: email, chatter, chatter-feed

On the Case object, I was able to set up the **Chatter component** and when I type something but don't send the email, it's saved automatically as a draft.

I need to enable that on Opportunity as well.

On Opportunity: I was able to see the send email composer on **Activities** component, but drafting is not available. I wasn't able to add the Email action on **Chatter**.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Case Feed uses a different email composer than what is used in the rest of the org. Not certain there's an alternative that will work for this unless you specify a different email composer.

Comment: It's the same Chatter component though, and I was hoping this is configurable somewhere in the setup, but I get that the case feed is a different thing.  Thanks.